# listing files with ADB using Python

Tags: python, android, regex, find, adb

I have a list of files under a directory in my Android device which I want to list, however I only want files without a dot(that is - no hidden files and files with explicit extensions).

I can do that in the mobile device with `find`:

```
find /mydir -type f -not -name *.*
```

And I can do the same with `adb` from my host (here I need the `\"` to protect my regex)

```
adb shell find /mydir -type f -not -name \"*.*\"
```

However I don't have a way to get it working in Python script triggered from my host. What I did is:

```
list_command = [
            'adb',
            'shell',
            'find',
            '/mydir'
            '-type',
            'f',
            '-not',
            '-name',
            r'\'*\.*\''
        ]
subprocess.check_output(list_command)
            .decode()
            .splitlines()
```

It actually gave me all the files regardless of whether a dot is presented in the path. What is the right way to run this `adb` command in Python?

Comment: actually, if I change the regex from `r'\'*\.*\''` to `'\'*\.*\''` it started to work. I thought `r` will ensure this raw string is passed down but turns out we don't need it.

Comment: I think you do not need to espcar the dot. Try with `"'*.*'"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are still passing a glob, not a regex, you should not escape the dot characters, use `"'*.*'"`:

```
list_command = [
            'adb',
            'shell',
            'find',
            '/mydir'
            '-type',
            'f',
            '-not',
            '-name',
            "'*.*'"
        ]
```

Just use it inside single quotes. Note you do not need to escape single quotes in a double quoted string literal, `"'*.*'"` is cleaner than the corresponding `'\'*.*\''` single quoted string literal.